# Camera following player is jerky and has bad visual effect

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a beginner and have an issue with camera following the player which is jerky. I have a player that moves only in upward direction on tapping, and other enemies that move in x direction. but when the player start jumping the camera starts jerky movements (specially near enemies) and also has a bad effect on enemies' movements too. Below is my code for CameraFollow.`

```
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {
[SerializeField]
private float yMin;
[SerializeField]
private float yMax;
[SerializeField]
private float xMin;
[SerializeField]
private float xMax;
private Transform target;


void Start () {     
    target = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
    //player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
}

void LateUpdate () {        
    transform.position = new Vector3 (Mathf.Clamp(target.position.x, xMin, xMax), Mathf.Clamp(target.position.y, yMin, yMax), transform.position.z);        
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)){
        Application.Quit ();            
    }       
}
```

Comment: could you take a moment to click Edit and remove the unnecessary white space / newlines from the code sample?  thanks

Comment: please note that **smooth follow** scripts are totally **builtin** to unity .. just click to add it.  google.  "standard assets"

Comment: can you provide me the link? thanks

Comment: no, i can't be bothered, sorry .. but try googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it jerks is because you're setting the transform of the camera directly, rather than (for example) smoothly lerping it.

I suggest using [Vector3.Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html).

Example, instead of:

`transform.position = new Vector3 (Mathf.Clamp(target.position.x, xMin, xMax), Mathf.Clamp(target.position.y, yMin, yMax), transform.position.z);`

try something like these lines:

```
Vector3 targetPos = new Vector3 (
    Mathf.Clamp(target.position.x, xMin, xMax),
    Mathf.Clamp(target.position.y, yMin, yMax),
    transform.position.z
    );

transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPos, 0.5f);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: still the same thing.. Camera jerky movement starts when player approaches enemy. Enemy moving in x direction and player is moving in y direction.

Comment: player is jumping with screen tap..

public Vector2 jumpForce = new Vector2(0, 200);

 void Start () {
  
 }
 
 void Update()
 {
  if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
   {            
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpForce);
  
   }
  }        
 }

Comment: I see. Could you try reducing the lerp factor i.e. use something like 0.1f (or even lesser if it is still jerky) as the 3rd parameter in the lerp function?

Comment: Try experimenting with the lerp factor till you find that it's smooth enough, but still not too fast or too slow. Let me know if it works.

Comment: camera is not moving with player with your given code

Comment: I mean, change the value between 0.1f and 0.5f, and see what works best.

Comment: nice answer @andeart

Comment: @SyedMuhammadSalmanShah Great. I strongly recommend following a couple tutorials from online first so you can get the hang of most common Unity mechanics, before trying out your own experiments. All the best! :)

Comment: This code actually shouldn't work smoothly. As Lerp (A,B,t) just defines a point beween a and b based on t value (0 for A and 1 for B), providing it with 0.5f will always return a point just in the middle between A and B thus still jumping there promptly. Instead of constant 0.5f one should use variable t which increments with Time.deltaTime * speed.